# canceling alarm in android using cancel ()

Tags: android

i made an android application using AlarmManager, it works fine but when i use cancel() to cancel the alarm it doesn't work fine and the alarm keeps working !!

here is making the alarm :

```
 private void setAlarm(Intent intentArg, int intentUnqId, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, boolean repeatAlarm)

{
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, intentUnqId, intentArg, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss ");
    Log.v("app", "Time is " + format.format(calendar.getTime()));

    AlarmManager alarmMngr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMngr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    if (repeatAlarm == true)
    {


        alarmMngr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000/*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES*/, pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

here is canceling the alarm :

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, intentID, intentArg, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmMngr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMngr.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id parameter you are passing to the `PendingIntent` to cancel the alarm is not the same as the one passed to the `PendingIntent` passed to the `AlarmManager` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method cancel(...) from AlarmManager, using the same PendingIntent you used to set the alarm. Example:

`this.getAlarmManager().cancel(mAlarmPendingIntent);` (this refers to the Activity or the Service from which you are cancelling the alarm).

Create the PendingIntent as:

```
mAlarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, flags);
```

also u can refer this link to do this 
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/cancel-android-alarm-44758.html

Answer (score 0):

The  intent used for setting alarm should match the intent used for canceling the alarm.

Intent match is done as per [public boolean filterEquals (Intent other)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29)

In `pendingIntent` used for `cancel()` use `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` flag instead  of `0`.